# mysql 27 second query (haversine vs geomfromtext)... must be a better way

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, haversine

I've shortened the tables to only show the relevant columns for this query.  It requires two tables and the queries are taking a long time and we've not even rolled into the 4+ million queries and a log file that is 30+ million records or a user table with 1+ million records.  It has me rethinking this... I need some guidance and suggestions:

Here's the table:

```
// an abreviated users table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=biz, 2=apt, 3=condo, 4=home',
  `distance` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0000000' COMMENT 'distance away to recv stuff',
  `lat` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
  `lon` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
  `location` point NOT NULL COMMENT 'GeomFromText',
  UNIQUE KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `distance` (`distance`),
  KEY `lat` (`lat`),
  KEY `lon` (`lon`),
  SPATIAL KEY `location` (`location`),
  KEY `idx_user_type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=501 ;
```

Here's the log table.

```
// pretty much the full log table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `some_log` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'record num',
  `userid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'user id receiving alert',
  `trackid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'id of msg from message table',
  `sent` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'when msg created',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_msg_log_userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `idx_msg_log_trackid` (`trackid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COMMENT='log of all of some stuff' AUTO_INCREMENT=62232;
```

Some sample data for the log file

```
INSERT INTO `some_log` (`id`, `userid`, `trackid`, `sent`) VALUES
(1, 1, 4, '2011-07-14 18:14:25'),
(2, 2, 4, '2011-07-14 18:14:25'),
(3, 13, 6, '2011-07-25 23:05:54'),
(4, 44, 7, '2011-08-09 16:20:02'),
(5, 12, 17, '2011-08-16 07:35:01'),
(6, 43, 17, '2011-08-16 07:35:01'),
(7, 45, 17, '2011-08-16 07:35:01'),
(8, 12, 18, '2011-08-16 08:05:01'),
(9, 43, 18, '2011-08-16 08:05:01'),
(10, 45, 18, '2011-08-16 08:05:01');
```

Here's the query.

```
// the query = $distance can be from 1/10th mile to 5 miles
SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($lat *pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat *pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180))* cos((($lon - `lon`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS dist_x 
   FROM `users`
   WHERE userid NOT IN (
      SELECT userid
      FROM some_log AS L
      WHERE L.trackid='$trackid')
   HAVING dist_x<='$distance' AND dist_x<=`distance` 
   ORDER BY dist_x ASC";
```

Here's another query. This one is slow.

```
// the above query is pretty quick given the test data
// this query is dog crap slow...
// we added in type and 4 is the most common type of user
SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($lat *pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat *pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180))* cos((($lon - `lon`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS dist_x 
   FROM `users`
   WHERE type='4' AND userid NOT IN (
      SELECT userid
      FROM some_log AS L
      WHERE L.trackid='$trackid')
   HAVING dist_x<='$distance' AND dist_x<=`distance` 
   ORDER BY dist_x ASC";
```

One question would be: Is there a radius/circle search that uses GeomFromText/POINT field vs the lat/lon search?

Another question: Is there a better way to check the some_log table for an entry where this $userid already has a $trackid?

Comment: Can you provide the results of EXPLAIN on your query? That might help figuring out why `WHERE type='4'` wrecked performance.

Comment: Are you certain that `type` is a string column? If it's an integer column, try `type = 4` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the spatial index and spatial column in the table.  They won't help you with lat-lon computations.

You can use your lat index to exclude whole bunches of pairs of points from the haversine computation.  Take advantage of this fact:  There are approx 69 statute miles, 60 nautical miles, or 111.045 km per degree of of latitude. (That's not exact, but it's pretty close).

So you can add a couple of conditions to your query. These will add a range-scan on your lat index, which is a *lot* faster than just your `HAVING` condition.

```
WHERE ....
  AND $lat >= lat - ($distance/69.0)
  AND $lat <= lat + ($distance/69.0)
  ...
```

This will exclude all your points that are too far north or too far south to be included in your haversine distance caLculation. This will save a lot of time.

You can also do this for lon, but the relationship between longitude and distance varies based on latitude. Longitude lines get closer together the closer you are to the poles. Therefore the formula is trickier.

Finally, `float` is a perfectly good data type for lat and lon.  You don't need high-precision decimal data for this application, unless you're a civil engineer and you care that the earth's true shape is a geoid, not a sphere.  If you care about that, you also better use a more precise distance formula than the haversine. But we're talking about differences of centimeters here -- big puddles in parking lots, but no problem for store finders.

Comment: …and if you care about geoids, you'll probably think haversine is an unacceptable simplification. :)

Comment: Ollie, great answer... we had just undergone a server migration and that process caused all sorts of problems (What worked on the old configuration was blowing up on the new).  Our required precision is to building level so will changing decimal to float cost us anything in precision vs. gaining anything in query speed?  Also, I read your response to suplementing the HAVING with $lat >= and $lat <= equations... is this correct?

Comment: `float` is fine for building-level resolution. It's also all you can get from gps resolution. You'll gain a tiny bit in query speed because MySQL needs to convert your decimal data to `double` to use the math functions.

Comment: Couple of more questions... other than the size issue, why not just create the fields as type double? Would there be a size vs performance issue? lat/lon queries can be done 4+ million times a year and could be on millions of users. At what point is the trade-off worth considering?  Next, $distance defaults to 5 miles but could be as little as 1/10 a mile (we routinely see .1, .25 and .5) so how will this affect the ($distance/69) since .1/69 = 0.0014492753623?

Comment: Here's the thing about latitude / longitude precision.  `float` is plenty of precision.  `double` is way too much for the data.  For me to claim my town's latitude is `42.79842367778193` is deceptive. As far as distance computations go `42.7984` is plenty close enough, and the difference between `42.798412345678` and `42.798400000000` is literally (for GPS) in the noise. That's why I advocate using `float` rather than `double`. You don't want an innumerate client or boss yelling at you about this imprecision, so don't store it.

Comment: 528 feet (0.1 mile) is a pretty doggone small radius. Civilian GPS gets as accurate about 10 feet, but no more accurate and often less accurate. If your location measurements are top-notch, the algorithm will work fine.   If you pick out your buildings on Google Earth, you'll get decent results.

Comment: 528 feet is very small but consider this: In NYC, the average city block (north of 14th st) is 1/5th mile (1,056 ft) by 1/20th mile (264 ft). If you were writing a parking spot finder app (I'm not) you could see how 528ft would make a huge difference in how accurate the app was and who got notified. This is true in most densly populated big cities. (and 264'x2 is 528' or two blocks! <grin>)

Comment: Yeah, and GPS is inaccurate in deep canyons, whether gneiss or concrete. Be careful!